# Numpy slow at boolean filtering of N-D array?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I came across a weirdly slow example of filtering a numpy array with boolean indices and wanted to get some explanation as to why it's happening, and how to speed it up.

Here's an IPython cell you can run yourself:

```py
import numpy as np

# normally I would load this from a file so this step doesn't matter so much
%timeit arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(2500, 3750, 4))
arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(2500, 3750, 4))

# This is fast enough
%timeit arr[..., 3] < 200

# This is where my complaint is
%timeit arr[arr[..., 3] < 200]

# dare you to try it with size=(5000, 7500, 4), this is where I first noticed it
```

with output

> 203 ms ± 4.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

> 23 ms ± 111 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

> 302 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

The last line feels very slow for what it's actually doing.

To be more specific this is exactly what I'm trying to do with the output:

```py
color = np.array([r, g, b])
arr[arr[..., 3] < 200] = arr[arr[..., 3] < 200]*0 + color
arr = arr[..., :3]
```

That is, I'm trying to handle the transparent channel of an image by replacing all transparent regions with a color and removing that channel.

Note, I don't want this to be specifically an image processing question. So to whoever doesn't know, the fourth channel of an image array is the alpha (transparency) channel, whereas the first 3 are typically your red, green, blue.

Comment: Is the output what you expect? I’m not all that confident in NumPy indexing, but `arr[..., 3] < 200` is a 2D Boolean array, and it might not do what you expect when used to index into a 3D array. In MATLAB this certainly would do something different than what you expect.

Comment: Yep, the output is as I expect

Comment: Are you sure this is working with arr.shape =(2500,3750,4) and color.shape == (3,)? Anyway if vectorization is to slow you could write it down with a few loops and an if statement and compile it (Numba or Cython). This will result in a runtime of about 10-20ms)